# ambiguity with すっと

Tags: usage, vocabulary, words

[WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E3%81%99%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8) says すっと means "quickly / all of a sudden" yet it can also mean "quietly / gently / softly"

So basically I was wondering how do we tell if すっと means "quickly / all of a sudden" or "quietly / gently / softly"?

E.g. in this sentence: カタツムリがすっと角を出した。

Does it mean:

1) Gently, the snail shot out its horns.

2) All of a sudden, the snail shot out its horns.

3) both 1) and 2) ?

Comment: try to click on the [Ex] link in WWWJDIC. That example is there with a translation. (maybe a better question is "when does "すっと" mean quietly/gently/softly)

Comment: the translation provided was "The snail shot out its horns.", but whether it was "gently" or "all of a sudden" was not written..

Comment: "shot" sounds like sudden to me

Comment: Keeping in mind we are talking about a snail... Suddenness is a relative matter.

Comment: ok, so basically I was wondering generally how do we tell if すっと means "quickly / all of a sudden" or "quietly / gently / softly"?

Comment: @Dave: Maybe you've seen a snail before, horns are pretty fast...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My dictionary defines すっと with these *four* meanings:

1. 真っすぐ，ほっそりと (straight or slender)
2. 素早く (quickly)
3. 滞りなく (without delay/obstacle)
4. 気分がさっぱりと (refreshed/neat/plain feelings)

So what do all these have in common? All of them vaguely mean *smooth*. I'd describe すっと as pretty much an onomatopoeia (though I don't think it's officially classified as such). In English you may say *zzzzzzip*.

> すっと伸びた枝 - a branch growing out *straight*

"The branch grows out like *zzzzzzzip*." (smooth and straight)

> すっと立って老人に席を譲った - He *immediately stood up* and gave his seat to the elderly

"He stood up like *zzzzzzip*." (in a flash, smoothly, without delay)

> 彼はすっと大学に入った - He was admitted to college *straight* out of high school

"He was admitted like *zzzzzzzip*." (smoothly, without delay)

> よく寝たので頭がすっとした - As I had a good sleep, I *feel refreshed*.

"My head feels like *zzzzzzzip*." (fresh, clear)

For your case, I think neither *quickly* nor *gently* translate very well:

> カタツムリがすっと角を出した。

"The snail extended her horns like *zzzzzzzzzip*."

In the case of a snail, that probably means both smooth and fast (as far as snails go). The horns just extended like *すっと*.

I hope this gives you more of a feel of how this is used. When used in speech, accompanied by a hand motion, it's pretty much self-explanatory. :)

Comment: this is pretty cool =D so basically.. it's supposed to be ambiguous?

Comment: It's not *supposed* to be ambiguous, it's a word that has no clear translation, but that you usually understand in context. 気持ちだよ、気持ち！ :-)

Answer (score 4):

Answer to your question is "3) both".

`すっと` is an onomatopea-derived adverb, and keep in mind that Japanese onomatopea has non-voiced vs. voiced pairs pretty much systematically. In general, there is a following contrast:

```
Non-voiced: quiet, gentle, soft, small, light, etc.
Voiced:     noisy, rough, hard, large, heavy, etc.
```

So, the voiced counterpart to `すっと` will be `ずっと`, which means a heavy large thing moved with sound. Other examples will be:

```
カリカリ scratching　: ガリガリ scraping
トントン knocking   :  ドンドン banging
パーン firecracker bursting : バーン bomb bursting
etc.
```

Comment: heys cool that's something new !

Comment: never noticed that. 勉強になった

Answer (score 2):

Deceze gave the most decent interpretation of すっと that I know of. On the other hand, the meaning "quietly / gently / softly" is more appropriately attributed to `そっと`. You can refer to Goo's [Dictionary (Digital Daijisen)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/130854/m0u/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8/) and [Thesaurus (Ruigo Reikai Jiten)](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/14476/m0u/) for usage examples.